# Set color scheme in global options on Rmarkdown R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to set a global color scheme in Rmarkdown, I read that this is possible with `options` but I tried this without success:

````
---
title: "Iris"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(ggplot2.continuous.color = "viridis")
options(ggplot2.continuous.fill = "viridis")
options(ggplot2.discrete.fill = "viridis")
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
   geom_point()
```
````

The plot I get uses the default color scheme, and I want the viridis scheme. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No solution, just a curious question: You set the options before you attach the library?

Comment: Hello @Martin Gal, seems that I did something wrong, didn't I? I loaded the tidyverse library before options but the colors stay the same (the default scheme). Thanks for the question, it made me rethink what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following [this excellent blog post by Jim Hester](https://www.jimhester.com/post/2013-03-11-ggplot-color-scales/), you can reassign to the default `scale_colour_*()` functions the scales you want:

````
---
title: "Iris"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
scale_colour_continuous <- scale_colour_viridis_c
scale_colour_discrete   <- scale_colour_viridis_d
scale_colour_binned     <- scale_colour_viridis_b
```

```{r}
iris %>% ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
   geom_point()
```
````

[image]

Comment: Hello @duckmayr, thank you!, great answer, works fine! By reading the blog post I see that I can handle other color schemes!. Have a great day!